# how to add buttons in content place holder at runtime in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-controls

In my form i have added one content place holder and also added a button within th e content place holder manually.But now i want to add a button in the same content place holder at runtime. I tried the following code, but the button is not showing in the browser...
I don't know what is the problem here...

My Code...

```
ContentPlaceHolder content = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("maincontent");
Button newButton = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button();
newButton.ID = "NextButton";
newButton.Text = "Next";
newButton.Visible = true;
content.Controls.Add(newButton);
```

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Put a Watch on `content` and see if: a) you've actually found it; b) it contains newButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've lost the size and location of your button.

Comment: thanks, here i added size by setting height and width.for giving location,we will use style.my needed location is style="margin-left: 148px".How do i assign this style for my button...

Answer (score 0):

Drop the

```
ContentPlaceHolder content = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("maincontent");
```

Change your code to

```
Button newButton = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button();
newButton.ID = "NextButton";
newButton.Text = "Next";
newButton.Visible = true;
maincontent.Controls.Add(newButton);
```

Assuming that 'maincontent' is the ID you've given your placeholder, or course.